# How to select following input elements and how to get part of the ID using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

There are many input elements which IDs are

> question5,question6, question7

,..., how to select these input elements using Jquery?

I do not mean `$('#question5')`, I mean to select the group of them.

Also How to get the the last number like 5,6,7,... using Jquery?

Comment: These input elements are dynamically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[id^='question']")
```

It will match input elements that have an `id` attribute that begin with `question`.

Once you have the elements, you can simply do a javascript substring on them to find the number:

```
$("input[id^='question']").each(function() {
    alert(this.id.substr(8));
});
```

Comment: These input elements are dynamically created.

Comment: That's fine, it won't make a difference.  As long as they are part of the DOM, jQuery selectors will find them.

Answer (score 2):

You can select all the `input` elements whose its `id` starts with `'question'`, and then you can extract the number, eg.:

```
$('input[id^=question]').blur(function () {
  var number = +this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
});
```

Just be careful because if the regular expression doesn't matchs, it will throw a `TypeError`, a safer version would be something like this:

```
$('input[id^=question]').blur(function () {
  var match = this.id.match(/\d+/);
  var number = match ? +match[0] : 0; // default zero
});
```

Comment: These input elements are dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to give the elements a common class that you can select:

```
<input id="question5" class="questions">
<input id="question6" class="questions">
<input id="question7" class="questions">
```

You cane then select all of them with `$(".questions")` and you can get their id:s with the jQuery [.attr()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#name) function.

Answer (score 0):

add a class to each input field.

```
<input class='questions'>
$('.questions')
```

using the select method on the class will do the trick

depending on what you are trying to do, using the jQuery selector for the class you can add a .each to iterate through the array, like so.

```
$('.questions').each(function (i){  
  //i = the current question number
  alert('this is question '+i);
});
```

Also, [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) is further documentation on the .each method in jQuery